# How to modify the subsequent code to obtain a condition based on which the rest is executed:

Tags: vba, excel

Good evening. I spend the better part of 5 hours trying to understand and find how to modify the below code to include a separate condition which determines whether the rest of the code for each row is executed or is skipped to the next row.

I cannot find anything. 
I tried to Dim the criteria as range (a column) but to no avail. I do not understand how to enter the condition. I either get **Next without For** or **If without End If** or other similar errors.

What I want to ask if there is a kind soul that might give me a clue as to where such statement should be inserted?
The statement is:

IF *corresponding cell* value is **value** then
       skip and do next i
Else do

```
If UCase(Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("L" & i).Value) Like "*" & UCase(Sheets("Rules").Range("A" & j).Value) & "*" Then
                Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("M" & i).Value = Sheets("Rules").Range("C" & j).Value
                PatternFound = True
```

The columns and sheets are:

**Sheet 1:**

*Column G* - contains 5 categories one of which is TAX. Based on that, IF IS TAX - skip, ELSE EXECUTE.

*Column L* - contains the description with keywords. Usualy 2-3 lines of text with 1 unique keyword in. 
*Column M* - where the categories based on the keywords are placed

**Sheet 2:**

*Column A* - the keywords to search for

*Column C* - the categories that should correspond next to each keyword (Gaz, Electricity etc.)

This is the original code below which needs modifying.

```
Sub Categories_Update()
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim PatternFound As Boolean

    Call speedup

    lastrow = Sheets("Rules").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To lastrow2

        PatternFound = False
        j = 1

        Do While PatternFound = False And j < lastrow
            j = j + 1
            If UCase(Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("L" & i).Value) Like "*" & UCase(Sheets("Rules").Range("A" & j).Value) & "*" Then
                Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("M" & i).Value = Sheets("Rules").Range("C" & j).Value
                PatternFound = True
            End If
        Loop

    Next i

    Call normal

End Sub

'-------------------------------

Public Sub speedup()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub

'-------------------------------

Public Sub normal()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the modification you are requesting is incorporated below (see asterisks & ensuing comments for explanation):

```
Sub Categories_Update()

Dim lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim PatternFound As Boolean

Call speedup

lastrow = Sheets("Rules").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To lastrow2

    ' *** I think this is what you are trying to insert, a conditional that causes the row to get skipped based on
    'column G being "TAX" - this conditional sends it to the part "Skip1" (you can call it anything) down below
    If UCase(Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("G" & i).Value) = "TAX" Then GoTo Skip1

    PatternFound = False
    j = 1

    Do While PatternFound = False And j < lastrow
        j = j + 1
        If UCase(Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("L" & i).Value) Like "*" & UCase(Sheets("Rules").Range("A" & j).Value) & "*" Then
            Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("M" & i).Value = Sheets("Rules").Range("C" & j).Value
            PatternFound = True
        End If
    Loop

    ' ***You need to add this piece to tell it where to skip to.  It has to have a colon after it.
Skip1:

    Next i

    Call normal

End Sub

'-------------------------------

Public Sub speedup()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub

'-------------------------------

Public Sub normal()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sir (apologies for the late answer) 
Let me test and get back shortly !

Comment: Hello Demetri, 

THANK YOU! It works perfectly. I modified it a little bit in order to include a wider range of possibilities (and succeded mind you) to the following


`If UCase(Sheets("DebitCard_Check").Range("G" & i).Value) Like "*TAX*" Then GoTo Skip1`





If I understood correctly as I dislike just copy pasting but also learning (its not the idea that someone else would write these for me everytime) 


The actual block of code that executes the loop starts from my original `Do While` part. 

end ends with `End Sub`

Comment: Therefore, in order to include a pre--cursor/filter that will command and direct the code, I had to include the bit before the begining of that loop. I hope I am correct. 

I was aiming at the same thing but failing because it seems my syntax naturally goes to C# and refused to wrap around VBA. Do you know of a good solid place where summarized I might find a good sheet with syntax for VBA? 

Other than the above -> THANK YOU! It is just what I was looking for.

Comment: That's funny as I have similar difficulties understanding c#, because my mind naturally goes to VBA.  I'm sorry that I don't know a place where you would necessarily find what you need, but here are two links to at least get you started: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx) [link](http://www.rondebruin.nl)  Good luck!

Comment: This is great! The links are actually awesome. And yeah, switching between languages is usually something super easy but when you are not familiar with the new language - goes from bad to worst :D